# Materialized sidenav collapse not working with $_SESSION

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm programming a little website for my local football team, where the only function in the side-nav is a login function (if you are not logged in, of course).
This is working.

But when I'm trying to display some other links in the sidenav on the user that just logged in, the sidenavn simply wont open. Where index.php's anchor links me to the sidenav toggle, admin.php simply returns websiteurl.dk/admin.php#

I've tried several solutions, but here is my current code in header.php (which is included on both admin.php and index.php:

```
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
            <?php if($_SESSION) { ?>
                <li><a href="?box">Bødekassen</a></li>
                <li><a href="?players">Spillere</a></li>
                <li><a href="?tickets">Bøder</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php?logout=true">Log ud</a></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <img class="logo-img-mobile" src="images/logo.png" alt=""/> 
                <form method="post" class="login-form-mobile"> 
                    <input type="text" placeholder="brugernavn" id="username" name="username" required /><br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password" required /><br>
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light loginBtn" type="submit" name="btn-login">Log ind</button>   
                </form>
            <?php } ?> 
        </ul>
```

Is more code needed? Please note me.

Comment: index.php can be found here: https://codeshare.io/5vON7a

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How exactly do I do that? With use of the backticks my code is kinda execute somehow.

Comment: Use the code block button `{}` after you have selected your code in the text window.

Comment: @JayBlanchard There you go, not quite sure how much code you need for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the anchor that toggles the sidenav in admin.php aswell (using this code : `$("#your_anchor").sideNav();`) ?

I guess you did in index.php since it's working but if you forgot it in admin.php that is probably the reason why it only returns  websiteurl.dk/admin.php#.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that some of my jQuery calls was placed wrong.

But still confusing since it worked on just one of the pages. But it works now, thanks for your time :-)